# How to refer a global variable as @pytest.mark.parametrize value in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have pytest file test_fixture2.py as below:

```
import pytest


param = None


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def module_setup():
    global param
    param = ["module var01", "module var02", "module var03"]


def test_globalvar():
    print(param)
```

It's works well with testcase test_globalvar and print param value as expect(['module var01', 'module var02', 'module var03']), **What I want to do is to transfered param value to @pytest.mark.parametrize value**, just like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("env", param)
def test_parametrize(env):
    print(env)
```

It's throw erros like below:

```
============================================================ ERRORS =============================================================
_________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/demo/test_fixture2.py __________________________________________ 
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:286: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:93: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:87: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:234: in pytest_pycollect_makeitem
    res = list(collector._genfunctions(name, obj))
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:403: in _genfunctions
    self.ihook.pytest_generate_tests.call_extra(methods, dict(metafunc=metafunc))
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:324: in call_extra
    return self(**kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:286: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:93: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:87: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:129: in pytest_generate_tests
    metafunc.parametrize(*marker.args, **marker.kwargs)
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:964: in parametrize
    function_definition=self.definition,
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\mark\structures.py:116: in _for_parametrize
    parameters = cls._parse_parametrize_parameters(argvalues, force_tuple)
venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\mark\structures.py:110: in _parse_parametrize_parameters
    ParameterSet.extract_from(x, force_tuple=force_tuple) for x in argvalues
E   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
======================================================= 1 error in 0.61s ========================================================
```

Looks the global param value not transfered to **@pytest.mark.parametrize("env", param)** correctly, how to handle this issue and make it as expected?

Comment: This happens because pytest generates the test permutations before evaluating the global variable. See: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3273